# Multipeer Connectivity sometimes don't send messages

Tags: ios, objective-c, multipeer-connectivity

I was studying About Multipeer Connectivity framework, and was looking for some simple tutorials on the internet, luckily found [this tutorial](http://techmaster.vn/2013/09/multipeer-connectivity-quick-tutorial/) which is quite simple to understand the structure and codes.

Unfortunately when I test this project in 2 devices (iPhone with an iPad ) , I realized that sometimes the message not reached to the final destination. I believe that should be a problem with the framework , perhaps it is not very accurate, or I could be wrong , and the problem could be in the code ?

Comment: As long as the devices remain connected, the framework is reliable. Is your code exactly the same as the tutorial?

Comment: @KeithCoughtrey, I think it yes, I test The project That I downloaded in the tutorial...

Comment: Please post some code and elaborate on what you are sending and the results you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link for a change, it has a sample code attached to it. check the part 2 version for file sharing option.

Link [Multipeer Connectivity](http://appcoda.com/intro-multipeer-connectivity-framework-ios-programming/)